# Can't see the last point in Highstock chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been working with Highstock chart and I noticed that when there are many points in the chart it's not possible to take a look at the last one using a tooltip:

[image: A chart with a tooltip]
You can see that the tooltip show point for 9th May, while there is another one for 10th May (as you can see in the range selector about: 24th May 2004 - 10th May 2011).

Is there a way to present to the user the last point, instead of the penultimate one ?

Comment: Cuold you setup jsFiddle demo? Most probably it's caused by [`dataGrouping`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping), which can be disabled, but you will lose performance.

Comment: I think even this sample illustrates the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/min-max/
(a default snippet from Highstock API doc).

Just change the range to "All"

Comment: And have you tried to disable dataGrouping as I said? Then it will display all points: http://jsfiddle.net/U2m4a/ (instead of grouped ones).

Comment: Can I use plotOptions -> series -> dataGrouping instead ? Due to some implementation problem, I can't modify "series" directly.

I used the following option:

plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    compare: 'percent',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        enabled: false,
                        groupPixelWidth: 1
                    }
                },
            },

Comment: OK Sir - your solution works fine for me. Please create an answer below and I'm happy to accept and upvote it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was caused by `dataGrouping`, disable it:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
         dataGrouping: { 
             enabled: false
         }
    }
}
```